# C# Is the TcpListener limited to local area network or is something wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcplistener, system.net

I have a problem with my chat app : it doesn't work over the network . I tried port-forwarding and other similar methods. I'm starting to question my code . I'm new to networking so please help me with this. I heard of another method using `System.Net.Sockets` but I haven't tried that yet . I heard that Sockets are pretty similar to `TcpListener` so I don't know what to say about this. I made sure I used the correct IP address , the `AddressFamily.InterNetwork`. Here is my code :

```
static TcpListener server;

public static void ListenThread()
        {
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream stream = null;
            ClientConnection currentClientConnection = new ClientConnection();
            while (true)
            {
                if(client == null)
                {
                    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    stream = client.GetStream();
                    currentClientConnection = new ClientConnection(client, stream);
                    clients.Add(currentClientConnection);
                    currentConnections++;

                    // Logging
                    string text = "A Client connection establieshed ! Connections : " + currentConnections;
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                    Logger.WriteToLog(text);
                }           

                int bufferSize = client.ReceiveBufferSize;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int i;
                string data = null;

                try
                {
                    while ((i = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
                    {
                        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, i);
                        data = ProcessData(data);

                        if (data == "/disconnect")
                        {
                            clients.Remove(currentClientConnection);
                            currentConnections--;

                            // Logging
                            string text = "A user left the server ! Connections : " + currentConnections;
                            Console.WriteLine(text);
                            Logger.WriteToLog(text);

                            SendToAllClients(string.Format("[Server]>> A user left the chat!"), client);
                            client.Close();
                            stream.Close();
                            client = null;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SendToAllClients(data, client);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { };
            }
        }
        static void InitialiseServer()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a port : ");
            serverPort = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            IPAddress localMachineIP = GetLocalIPAddress();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Initialising Server...");
                server = new TcpListener(localMachineIP,serverPort);
                Console.WriteLine("Server initialised !");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                string text = string.Format("An error has occured while initalising server under IP={0} and port={1} . {2}", localMachineIP, serverPort, e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                Logger.WriteToLog(text);
                Console.ForegroundColor = baseColor;
            }

            Console.Title = string.Format("Server initailised under {0}:{1}",localMachineIP.ToString(),serverPort);
        }

public static IPAddress GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Blocked by firewall, perhaps?

Comment: IP you can have Internet or Intranet networks.  Internet you can access from any way in the world.  Intranet are local networks that are limited.  So you can only connect within network.  You can try using the Computer name instead of the IP address which may work.  Router discovery to find a IP address may be disabled or blocked by routers.  So you may need to use the name instead of the IP.

Comment: "it doesn't work over the network", can you expand on this ? are you getting any errors? Maybe add some logging so you can pin point where it is falling down

Comment: @jdweng . TcpListener does not have an option for using hostname instead of IP . Swiching to sockets would require me a lot of rework , so I don't know what to say about this approach . But thank you anyway for help

Comment: @level_zebra . My chat app only work in the local area network , in other words , only with my router . I want to make over the network , able to send data trough the internet , to another client at another end . It works perfectly , without any errors , all the function and features of the app work exactly as intended .

Comment: Yes it does.  It will either accept a string IP or string Hostname.  They are both strings.  Best thing to do is from cmd.exe >Ping IP or Hostname.  First get Ping to work before trying from c#.  If ping will not work than c# also will not work.

Comment: A listener should be using IP.Any as the endpoint and not an IP address. IP.Any will receive connections when you have more than one IP address for the machine.  When you have more than one IP on the machine using will only allow connections from one IP.

Comment: @jdweng I'm trying this right now . The first thing I noticed is that the `TcpListener` actually does not take a `string` as a parameter for IP , but an `IPAddress` or `IPEndPoint` , but you can actually just specify the port alone without an IP , but I get warning that's deprecated so I had to use the tag `[Obsolete]` to my function. I will wait for my mate to help me test this over the network. In local network works just fine .

Comment: @jdweng On second taught , I noticed that as an parameter for `IPEndPoint` you can just use `IPAddress.Any` . I've been ignorant here , I'm sorry . You're the best man , thank you for your help . Now I just have to test it over the network .

Comment: @jdweng I have tried with my mate and it doesn't work . I have converted my IP to an static one and it still doesn't work . What can it be ? Do I have to port-forward with my router ?

Comment: Try Ping from cmd.exe.  You first need a route which ping will test before you attempt a c# application.  Try with IP and computer name both from local machine and remote machine to determine what works and what does not work.  If you have routers and different network try all to see what works and what doesn't to narrow down the cause of the issue.  The more information you have to easier it will be to determine why you do not have a route.

Comment: You can't put a any PC onto the internet, otherwise you would have duplicate IP on the Internet.  You carrier assigns one IP to your house.  Any internal PC are only on a private network.

Comment: @jdweng I told my friend to ping my static ip and lost all 4 packets . So it's from my machine . What should I do now ? Do I have to change my IP Adress ?

Comment: If your pc is the gateway to your internet provider than nothing.  Your provider is not giving you a public IP address.  And if your PC is in your private network again you cannot do anything since you cannot just assign a random IP to a computer without registering the IP so it is unique.

Comment: @jdweng So i have to talk to my provider and get a public IP Adress.

Comment: @jdweng I figured out my public IP Adress but when I try to start my server it get's this error : `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=The requested address is not valid in its context
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
   at Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
`

Comment: A Server should use as an endpoint IPAddress.Any instead of a IP.  If a machine has more than one IP then Any will listen to all IP rather than on in particular.  It is also better to use Any when the client and listener is on the same machine so you do not get any conflicts.  You also should make sure the IP is valid.First I would check if your machine is using the IP from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG -ALL (IP V4 address).   Also from cmd.exe >PING IP (where IP is the address you were given).

Comment: @jdweng I think i know the cause of all of this. Its about port forwarding. The thing is, i tried doing it, and it seemed to work, so i tested if the port was open (2020) and it said the port was closed. I have a ZTE F660RV1, its not a router from what i know, so maybe That's the problem i guess

Comment: This has nothing to do with port forwarding which you should not be using in a local network.  Port forwarding is only used if the port is blocked by a virus checker or firewall.  The solution if it is blocked then unblock the port number.  But usually only ports under 1000 are blocked.  You do not have a route to the device.  First get ping working from cmd.exe.  Normally on a local network IP are advertised using ARP (what ping uses).   You can see the ARP table from cmd.exe >ARP -A. You should have a route to device using IP and Mask.  So the router is not allowing the IP to pass to device.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry for not understanding , but what can I use from this table (ARP table) ? Do I have to connect to my server with one of these IP Adresses ?

Comment: The ARP table indicates the IP addresses in your local Network (or ping responses).  Every IP device will ARP when turned on and then repeatedly (usually 30 minutes).  The ARP table will remove an IP every hour doesn't get an ARP.  Items are added to ARP when the device sends an ARP.  Since a ping is an ARP (to device) and gets an ARP Response (from device), the PING responses are also added to the ARP Table.